# AngularJS Generic function that returns loaded controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

looking for a function that returns me the name of any loaded controller. Or is there a function that i can call after everything is initialized and access all controller names and scopes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect an angular module's _invokeQueue to find all registered components.

And if a module is dependant on another, you can inspect a modules requires array.

```
app.service('Names', function () {
  return {
    allInModule: function () {
      return _.map(app._invokeQueue, function (inv) {
        return {
          type: inv[1],
          name: inv[2][0]
        };
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Check out this plunker to see how it works

http://plnkr.co/edit/XmDF94?p=preview